# Alternative to shouldPerformSegue without an identifier

Tags: swift, xcode

I have an app where I'm updating the labels on buttons, to prevent having to make an extremely similar View Controller twice.

As this is in a navigation controller, I want the first 'Back' press to reverse this label change if it has occurred (I am aware that the button label points to the previous view controller's title, but I can work around this for now).

I was therefore wondering if there was an alternative to shouldPerformSegue that didn't need an identifier or whether I'd have to either build my own Navigation Bar or a separate View Controller to accomplish this.

TIA

Comment: It would help to see the actual code you've written to illustrate what you've already tried.

Answer (score 0):

I do not have access to a computer at this moment, but if I remember it correctly, should be something like this:

```
//Whenever you want to trigger the segue

//Initiate an instance of a ViewController from the view controller class
let newViewController = SecondViewController()
//push the created view controller into your current navigation controller
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(newViewController, animated: true)
```

As for the back button, not sure I understand what was your question, but if you wanted to change the title then you can simply do that with this line:

```
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "CustomTitleString", style: .plain, target: nil, action: nil)
```